# Role based authorization in identity server 4 with .Net core web API

Tags: asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core, oauth-2.0, identityserver4, asp.net-core-webapi

I am new to .net core. I am working on role based authorization with identity server 4. I have implemented role based authorization it gives me "500 internal server error" When I remove role from the authorize attribute it gives me successful result.

my application layout like as

1. Client(Postman)
2. Identity Server4 (auth server)
3. .Net core Web API application

### Identity Server code

#### Config file

```
public class Config
{
    public static IEnumerable<ApiResource> GetApiResources()
    {
        return new List<ApiResource>{
            new ApiResource("dataEventRecords")
            {
                ApiSecrets =
                {
                    new Secret("dataEventRecordsSecret".Sha256())
                },
                Scopes =
                {
                    new Scope
                    {
                        Name = "dataeventrecordsscope",
                        DisplayName = "Scope for the dataEventRecords ApiResource"
                    }
                },
                UserClaims = { "role", "admin", "user", "dataEventRecords", "dataEventRecords.admin", "dataEventRecords.user" }
            },
            new ApiResource("securedFiles")
            {
                ApiSecrets =
                {
                    new Secret("securedFilesSecret".Sha256())
                },
                Scopes =
                {
                    new Scope
                    {
                        Name = "securedfilesscope",
                        DisplayName = "Scope for the securedFiles ApiResource"
                    }
                },
                UserClaims = { "role", "admin", "user", "securedFiles", "securedFiles.admin", "securedFiles.user" }
            }
        };
    }

    public static IEnumerable<IdentityResource> GetIdentityResources()
    {
        return new List<IdentityResource>    {
                    new IdentityResources.OpenId(),
                    new IdentityResources.Profile(),
                    new IdentityResource("dataeventrecordsscope",new []{ "role", "admin", "user", "dataEventRecords", "dataEventRecords.admin" , "dataEventRecords.user" } ),
                    new IdentityResource("securedfilesscope",new []{ "role", "admin", "user", "securedFiles", "securedFiles.admin", "securedFiles.user"} )
        };
    }

    public static IEnumerable<Client> GetClients()
    {
        return new List<Client>
        {
            new Client
            {
                ClientName = "Authclient",
                ClientId = "client",
                AllowedGrantTypes = GrantTypes.ResourceOwnerPassword,
                ClientSecrets =
                {
                    new Secret("dataEventRecordsSecret".Sha256())
                },

                AllowedScopes = new List<string>
                {
                    "openid",
                    "email",
                    "profile",
                    "dataEventRecords",
                    "aReallyCoolScope",
                    "role"
                }
            },
        };
    }

    public static List<TestUser> GetUsers()
    {
        return new List<TestUser>
        {
            new TestUser
            {
                SubjectId = "1",
                Username = "test",
                Password = "test"
            },
            new TestUser
            {
                SubjectId = "2",
                Username = "test1",
                Password = "test1"
            },
            new TestUser{SubjectId = "48421157", Username = "damienbodadmin", Password = "damienbod",
              Claims = new Claim[]
              {
                new Claim("Name", "damienbodadmin"),
                new Claim("GivenName", "damienbodadmin"),
                new Claim("Email", "damien_bod@hotmail.com"),
                new Claim("EmailVerified", "true", ClaimValueTypes.Boolean),
                new Claim("Role", "admin"),
                new Claim("Role", "dataEventRecords.admin"),
                new Claim("Role", "dataEventRecords.user"),
                new Claim("Role", "dataEventRecords")
              }
            },
            new TestUser{SubjectId = "48421158", Username = "damienboduser", Password = "damienbod",
              Claims = new Claim[]
              {
                new Claim("Name", "damienboduser"),
                new Claim("GivenName", "damienboduser"),
                new Claim("Email", "damien_bod@hotmail.com"),
                new Claim("EmailVerified", "true", ClaimValueTypes.Boolean),
                new Claim("Role", "user"),
                new Claim("Role", "dataEventRecords.user"),
                new Claim("Role", "dataEventRecords")
              }
            }
        };
    }
}
```

#### startup.cs

```
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        var mySqlConnectionString = configuration.GetConnectionString("mySqlConnectionString");

        services.AddIdentityServer()
        .AddTemporarySigningCredential()
        .AddInMemoryIdentityResources(Reflexion_HLTR_AuthServer.Config.Config.GetIdentityResources())
        .AddInMemoryApiResources(Reflexion_HLTR_AuthServer.Config.Config.GetApiResources())
        .AddInMemoryClients(Reflexion_HLTR_AuthServer.Config.Config.GetClients())
        .AddTestUsers(Reflexion_HLTR_AuthServer.Config.Config.GetUsers());

        services.AddAuthorization(options =>
        {
            options.AddPolicy("dataEventRecordsAdmin", policyAdmin =>
            {
                policyAdmin.RequireClaim("role", "dataEventRecords.admin");
            });
            options.AddPolicy("dataEventRecordsUser", policyUser =>
            {
                policyUser.RequireClaim("role", "dataEventRecords.user");
            });

        });

    }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
    {
        loggerFactory.AddConsole(LogLevel.Debug);
        app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();

        app.UseIdentityServer();

        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        }

        app.Run(async (context) =>
        {
            await context.Response.WriteAsync("Hello World!");
        });

    }
```

### Web API

#### Startup.cs

```
 public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
    {
        loggerFactory.AddConsole(Configuration.GetSection("Logging"));
        loggerFactory.AddDebug();

        app.UseIdentityServerAuthentication(new IdentityServerAuthenticationOptions
        {
            Authority = "http://localhost:5000",
            RequireHttpsMetadata = false,
            RoleClaimType = ClaimTypes.Role,
            ApiName = "dataEventRecords"                
        });

        app.UseMvc();

    }
```

#### EmloyeeController.cs

```
[Route("api/Employee")]
[Authorize]
public class EmployeeController : Controller
{
    #region Private Fields
    private IEmployeeService _IEmployeeService = null;
    #endregion

    #region Constructor
    public EmployeeController(IEmployeeService _IEmployeeService)
    {
        this._IEmployeeService = _IEmployeeService;
    }
    #endregion

    // GET: api/Employee
    [HttpGet]
    [Authorize(Policy = "dataEventRecordsUser")]
    public JsonResult Get()
    {
        var emp = _IEmployeeService.GetEmployee().ToList();
        return Json(emp);
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you have code somewhere to create those roles if they don't exist?

Comment: Frank, Sorry I am not catching you clearly. I don't have anything else from code side. Can you please elaborate?

Comment: I apologize. Please disregard my comment, I hadn't properly read through the snippets. I'm not familiar enough with user auth using identity server

Comment: You should provide the details to your exception. 500 Internal Server Error is not enough. You should be able to see your error in the Console or Debug Console. Please provide this information.

Comment: Svek, InnerException = {System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: Response status code does not indicate success: 500 (Internal Server Error).
   at System.Net.Http.HttpResponseMessage.EnsureSuccessStatusCode()
   at System.Net.Http.HttpClient.<GetContentAsync>d__32`1.MoveNext()})

Comment: stack trace is :    at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.ThrowIfExceptional(Boolean includeTaskCanceledExceptions)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1.GetResultCore(Boolean waitCompletionNotification)
   at ReflexionConsole.Program.CallApi(TokenResponse response) in F:\Reflexion_HLTR\ReflexionConsole\ReflexionConsole\Program.cs:line 44
   at ReflexionConsole.Program.Main(String[] args) in F:\Reflexion_HLTR\ReflexionConsole\ReflexionConsole\Program.cs:line 14

Comment: Thank you guys for your response, I have done it, I was not setting up the roles properly in the claims.

Answer (score 0):

I have modified the AllowedScopes section in the GetClients() method like as

```
AllowedScopes = new List<string>
{
     ClaimTypes.Role
}
```

Then it works for me.